# Fireworks Animation on a Specific Point on Graph

Tags: r

[image]How can I have this fireworks animation play on a specific point on a line plot graph animation, below:

I have this animation that creates the effect of fireworks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(gganimate)
library(magick)

#Explosion 
for (z in 1:3) { 
p1 <- map_dfr(1:10, ~crossing(x = runif(30),
nesting(
y = seq(1, .x, length.out = 10)^0.5,
t = 1:10))
)%>%
ggplot(aes(x, y=y+z)) +
geom_point(color = 'red') +
coord_polar() +
transition_time(t) +
shadow_wake(0.5) 
}
p2_gif <- animate(p1, renderer = gifski_renderer(), nframes = 70, fps = 50, width = 250, height = 250)
anim_save("~/Downloads/EV2.gif")
```

How can I have the fireworks animation play at the highest point in this GGanimate plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(ggthemes)
library(forcats)
library(scales)
library(transfrmr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggbreak) 
library(patchwork)
library(magick)


don <- readr::read_csv("~/Downloads/anim_test5.csv")

Months= as.Date(don$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")



a2<- don %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Months)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = Cumulative), color="#C91D42",  alpha=0.4) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Cumulative), color="#C91D42",  alpha=0.4) +
    theme_economist() +
    scale_colour_economist() +
    ylab("Spend in £ (Cumulative)") +
    xlab("Dates")+
    scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2023-02-14", "2023-04-21")), 
    date_breaks = "2 week", date_labels = "%d-%m")+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = gbp)+
    transition_reveal(Months)+
    shadow_wake(0.2, alpha = 0.4, colour = "#C91D42", exclude_layer = 3)

   quartz()
   plot(a2)
        
   animate(a2, height = 800,width = 1000, units = "px", res = 230, detail = 5, 
   end_pause = 8,  fps=10, duration = 10)
        
   anim_save("~/Downloads/Simple2.gif")
```

[image]

Data in anim_test5.csv

| Date | Cumulative |
| --- | --- |
| 24-Feb-23 | 3187.5 |
| 03-Mar-23 | 5482.5 |
| 10-Mar-23 | 11347.5 |
| 17-Mar-23 | 13642.5 |
| 24-Mar-23 | 16702.5 |
| 31-Mar-23 | 28690.5 |
| 07-Apr-23 | 39403.75 |
| 14-Apr-23 | 61754.75 |
| 21-Apr-23 | 89062.75 |

Beyond my technical ability to merge two GGAnimate plots to play one after the other in the same GIF. I am not able to make the fireworks occur at a particular point (highest value) on the animated plot

Comment: @SamR, Thank you for taking a look. I've removed the comprss function, as it was not needed. Also fixed the code, after transition_reveal.

Answer (score 13):

We can start by reading in your data and loading the *necessary* libraries:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

don <- data.frame(Date = c("24-Feb-23", "03-Mar-23", "10-Mar-23", "17-Mar-23",
                           "24-Mar-23", "31-Mar-23", "07-Apr-23", "14-Apr-23", 
                           "21-Apr-23"), 
                  Cumulative = c(3187.5, 5482.5, 11347.5, 13642.5, 
                                 16702.5, 28690.5, 39403.75, 61754.75, 
                                 89062.75))
```

Now we'll modify your date strings into actual dates and then to numeric values (you'll see why in a minute). We'll also add a `Time` variable to keep track of events in the animation.

```r
don <- don %>%
  mutate(Months = as.Date(Date, "%d-%b-%y"), 
         Time = seq(1, 9, length = 9),
         Months = as.numeric(Months))
```

The trickiest part is making the firework animation in Cartesian rather than polar co-ordinates, and making sure its scale matches the scale of your data. We need to work in numeric values here, hence the conversion from dates to numbers.

```r
firework <- data.frame(theta = runif(20, 0, 2*pi),
                       len = sqrt(runif(20))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(len = len, theta = (theta + 0:5 * pi/3) %% (2*pi)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(Time = c(1, seq(9, 11, length.out = 10)), 
          Months = c(0, seq(0, len, length = 10)) * cos(theta) * 10 + 
                   as.numeric(max(don$Months)),
          Cumulative = c(0, seq(0, len, length = 10)) * sin(theta) * 15000 + 
                   max(don$Cumulative))
```

Lastly, we have our animation code. The fireworks get their own `geom_point` layer.

```r
a1 <- don %>%
  ggplot(aes(Months, Cumulative)) +
  geom_line(color = "#C91D42") +
  geom_point(color = "#C91D42") +
  geom_point(data = firework, size = 0.1,
             aes(color = ifelse(Time < 9, NA, "red"))) +
  shadow_wake(0.04, alpha = 0.5, exclude_layer = 1) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  ggthemes::theme_economist() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10))) +
  ylab("Spend in £ (Cumulative)") +
  xlab("Dates") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 19408 + 0:5 * 14, limits = c(19408, NA),
                     labels = ~format(as.Date(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
                                      "%d-%m")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("£0", "£25k", "£50k", "£75k", "£100k"),
                     breaks = seq(0, 100000, 25000)) +
  transition_reveal(Time)

animate(a1, height = 800, width = 1000, units = "px", res = 230, detail = 5, 
        end_pause = 0,  fps = 20, duration = 5, device = "ragg_png")
```

[image]

Personally, I think the firework looks a little odd. I would probably add in some extra calculations to emulate momentum, gravity and heat:

```r
set.seed(1)
firework <- data.frame(theta = runif(20, 0, 2*pi),
                       len = sqrt(runif(20, 0, 3)),
                       point = seq(20)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(len = len, theta = (theta + 0:5 * pi/3) %% (2*pi),
          point = paste(point, 0:5)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(Time = seq(9, 14, length.out = 25), 
          Months = seq(0, len, length = 25) * cos(theta) * 10 + 
            as.numeric(max(don$Months)) + seq(0, 5, len = 25),
          Cumulative = seq(0, len, length = 25) * sin(theta) * 17000 + 
            max(don$Cumulative) + seq(0, 50000, len = 25) -
            seq(0, 250, len = 25)^2,
          point = point)
```

Which gives us

```r
a1 <- don %>%
  ggplot(aes(Months, Cumulative)) +
  geom_point(data = firework, size = 0.2, 
             aes(color = ifelse(Time < 9, NA, Time), group = point,
                 alpha = ifelse(Time < 9, 0, (14 - Time)/5))) +
  geom_line(color = "#C91D42") +
  geom_point(color = "#C91D42") +
  shadow_wake(0.2, alpha = 0, exclude_layer = 2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("white", "yellow", "orange","red",
                                   "gray30", "#ccdee6"), 
                        guide = "none") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  ggthemes::theme_economist() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        plot.margin = margin(12, 50, 12, 0)) +
  ylab("Spend in £ (Cumulative)") +
  xlab("Dates") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 19408 + 0:4 * 14, limits = c(19408, NA),
                     labels = ~format(as.Date(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
                                      "%d-%m")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("£0", "£25k", "£50k", "£75k", "£100k"),
                     breaks = seq(0, 100000, 25000)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(19408, 19470)) +
  transition_reveal(Time)

animate(a1, height = 800, width = 1000, units = "px", res = 230, detail = 5, 
        end_pause = 0,  fps = 20, duration = 5, device = "ragg_png")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To demystify the code a bit, here are the parameters written out to create the firework object and demonstrated on the additional data provided by the OP

```r
don <- don %>%
  mutate(Months = as.Date(Date, "%d-%b-%y"), 
         Time = seq(1, 45, length = 45),
         Months = as.numeric(Months))

n_frames   <- 50
n_points   <- 45
start      <- 45
stop       <- 90
x_scale    <- 40
x_momentum <- 30
y_scale    <- 300000
y_momentum <- 5000
gravity    <- 500

set.seed(2)
firework <- data.frame(theta = runif(n_points, 0, 2*pi),
                       len = sqrt(runif(n_points, 0, 3)),
                       point = seq(n_points)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(len = len, theta = (theta + 0:5 * pi/3) %% (2*pi),
          point = paste(point, 0:5)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(Time = seq(start, stop, length.out = n_frames), 
          Months = seq(0, len, length = n_frames) * cos(theta) * x_scale + 
            as.numeric(max(don$Months)) + seq(0, x_momentum, len = n_frames),
          Cumulative = seq(0, len, length = n_frames) * sin(theta) * y_scale + 
            max(don$Cumulative) + seq(0, y_momentum, len = n_frames) -
            seq(0, gravity, len = n_frames)^2,
          point = point)
```

And the plot is

```r
a1 <- don %>%
  ggplot(aes(Months, Cumulative)) +
  geom_point(data = firework, size = 0.1, 
             aes(color = ifelse(Time < 45, NA, Time), group = point,
                 alpha = ifelse(Time < 45, 0, (90 - Time)/5))) +
  geom_line(color = "#C91D42") +
  geom_point(color = "#C91D42") +
  shadow_wake(0.2, alpha = 0, exclude_layer = 2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("white", "yellow", "orange","red",
                                   "gray30", "#ccdee6"), 
                        guide = "none") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  ggthemes::theme_economist() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=6), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        plot.margin = margin(12, 50, 12, 0)) +
  ylab("Spend in £ (Cumulative)") +
  xlab("Dates") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 19408 + 0:45 * 30, limits = c(19408, NA),
                     labels = ~format(as.Date(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
                                      "%d-%m")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("£0", "£250k", "£500k", "£750k", 
                                "£1M", "£1.2M", "£1.5M"),
                     breaks = seq(0, 1500000, 250000)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(19408, 19750)) +
  transition_reveal(Time)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Please can you share what constants/variables in the code can be used to adjust fireworks' parameters (width, etc)?

Comment: Please see code below.

Answer (score 0):

@allan cameron

Thank you for the brilliant answer. When extended for larger cumulative values the fireworks flatten out. What parameters when adjusted will get the full FW effect?

I've made some changes and this is the final output

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)



library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

don <- data.frame(Date = c("24-Feb-23", "03-Mar-23", "10-Mar-23", "17-Mar-23", "24-Mar-23", "31-Mar-23", "07-Apr-23", "14-Apr-23", "21-Apr-23", "28-Apr-23", "05-May-23", "12-May-23", "19-May-23", "26-May-23", "02-Jun-23", "09-Jun-23", "16-Jun-23", "23-Jun-23", "30-Jun-23", "07-Jul-23", "14-Jul-23", "21-Jul-23", "28-Jul-23", "04-Aug-23", "11-Aug-23", "18-Aug-23", "25-Aug-23", "01-Sep-23", "08-Sep-23", "15-Sep-23", "22-Sep-23", "29-Sep-23", "07-Oct-23", "14-Oct-23", "20-Oct-23", "27-Oct-23", "03-Nov-23", "10-Nov-23", "17-Nov-23", "24-Nov-23", "01-Dec-23", "08-Dec-23", "15-Dec-23", "22-Dec-23", "29-Dec-23"), 
                  Cumulative = c(3187.50, 5482.50, 11347.50, 13642.50, 16702.50, 28690.50, 39403.75, 61754.75, 89062.75, 125679.75, 144307.75, 182238.75, 234663.25, 284059.75, 327346.75, 380281.25, 430505.25, 483697.25, 530820.75, 585259.75, 635097.25, 684121.75, 732300.25, 779469.25, 833029.25, 872117.75, 911322.25, 948178.25, 1003158.25, 1050036.75, 1091477.25, 1135424.75, 1177254.75, 1211622.25, 1241879.25, 1268785.25, 1297236.15, 1313814.25, 1337804.25, 1358920.55, 1388891.59, 1407157.59, 1427444.59, 1438359.59, 1438359.59))


rcumulative<- comprss(don$Cumulative)

don <- don %>%
  mutate(Months = as.Date(Date, "%d-%b-%y"), 
         Time = seq(1, 45, length = 45),
         Months = as.numeric(Months))

set.seed(2)
firework <- data.frame(theta = runif(45, 0, 2*pi),
                       len = sqrt(runif(45, 0, 3)),
                       point = seq(45)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(len = len, theta = (theta + 0:5 * pi/3) %% (2*pi),
          point = paste(point, 0:5)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(Time = seq(45, 90, length.out = 45), 
          Months = seq(0, len, length = 45) * cos(theta) * 10 + 
            as.numeric(max(don$Months)) + seq(0, 5, len = 45),
          Cumulative = seq(0, len, length = 45) * sin(theta) * 300000 + 
            max(don$Cumulative) + seq(0, 5000, len = 250) -
            seq(0, 250, len = 45)^2,
          point = point) 

a1 <- don %>%
  ggplot(aes(Months, Cumulative)) +
  geom_point(data = firework, size = 0.1, 
             aes(color = ifelse(Time < 45, NA, Time), group = point,
                 alpha = ifelse(Time < 45, 0, (90 - Time)/5))) +
  geom_line(color = "#C91D42") +
  geom_point(color = "#C91D42") +
  shadow_wake(0.2, alpha = 0, exclude_layer = 2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("white", "yellow", "orange","red",
                                   "gray30", "#ccdee6"), 
                        guide = "none") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  ggthemes::theme_economist() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=6), 
axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        plot.margin = margin(12, 50, 12, 0)) +
  ylab("Spend in £ (Cumulative)") +
  xlab("Dates") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 19408 + 0:45 * 30, limits = c(19408, NA),
                     labels = ~format(as.Date(.x, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
                                      "%d-%m")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("£0", "£250k", "£500k", "£750k", "£1M", "£1.2M", "£1.5M"),
                     breaks = seq(0, 1500000, 250000)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(19408, 19750)) +
  transition_reveal(Time)


  
          quartz()
        
        plot(a1)

animate(a1, height = 600, width = 1000, units = "px", res = 230, detail = 5, end_pause = 0,  fps = 20, duration = 5, device = "ragg_png")

        
anim_save("~/Downloads/Fireworks/FireworksX_FULL33.gif")
```

[image]